# Using r-squared values to correlate two values that can't be measured at the same time

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I have data A and B that can be measured at the same time and have an R^2 value of 0.91.  I also have data B and C that can be measured at the same time and have and R^2 value of 0.89.  Is there a way to estimate the R^2 value of A and C?

Edit to add example plots.[image: Data A v B and B v C]  I'm looking for the assumed R^2 value of A v C.

Comment: Could you give some example data?

Comment: What do the colors mean?

Comment: In the A v B plot the green is data B with a R^2 of .91.  The red in the first and second plot have no relation.  Sorry I can't replot the first one for more clarity.

Comment: I can't collect Data A under the same conditions as Data C.  I'm looking to use Data B as an intermediary to estimate the R^2 between A and C.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming standardized $(A,B,C)$

$$R(A,B)=A^TB\\
R(C,B)=C^TB$$

$$A=B\cdot R(A,B)+U_A\\
C=B\cdot R(C,B)+U_C$$

$$R(A,C)=A^TC=(B\cdot R(A,B)+U_A)^T(B\cdot R(C,B)+U_C)=\\
R(A,B)\color{blue}{(B^TB)}R(C,B)
+R(A,B)\color{red}{(B^TU_C)}
+\color{red}{(U_A^TB)}R(C,B)
+(U_A^TU_C)=\\
R(A,B)R(C,B)
+(U_A^TU_C)
$$

---

It's easy to show that $B^TU_C=U_A^TB=0$

$$B^TU_C = B^T(C-B\cdot R(C,B)) = B^TC-\color{blue}{B^TB} \cdot R(C,B) = R(C,B)-1\cdot R(C,B) = 0$$

---

If you can reasonably assume that the covariance between errors is $(U_A^TU_C)\approx0$, then $R^2(A,C)\approx R^2(A,B)R^2(C,B)$.
However, if the covariance is non-zero you'll either under or overestimate it.

---

Notice that the variances of the errors are guaranteed to be smaller than 1:
$$U_C^TU_C = C^TC^+B^TB\cdot R^2(C,B)-(C^TB+B^TC)\cdot R(C,B) =\\ 1 + R^2(C,B)-2R^2(C,B)=1-R^2(C,B)$$